# How to append array in python using Numpy

Tags: numpy

I am new to python, Can you please tell me how to append an array with an empty array.

I want output like this `[[2,6] [5, 4]]`. can you please suggest?

I do not want output like below

[image]

Please note, values I am willing to append with a are coming from the loop. So I want some generic solution

Comment: Don't do this. Appending to a empty list is fine, but a poor model for working with arrays.

Comment: If you are new to python and numpy, you should be checking the official documentation.  Here you missed what `np.append` says about the `axis`.  Also you have a poor grasp of what array dimensions are.  Your first "empty" array is not have the right shape for concatenating with 2d arrays.  Don't skip the basics!

Comment: @hpaulj, yes. array 'a' will have any number of rows but columns would be the same size, in my example, it would be 2. I wanted to keep appending an array of size 2 with the main array 'a'. I am following official documentation only

Comment: `np.append` is a poorly named and conceived function.  It should not be used as though it were a list `append` clone.  If you don't understand `np.concatenate`, you won't be able to use `np.append` correctly either.  Start with a list append as I demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

The `np.append` function flattens the inputs if the `axis` parameter is not supplied (as stated [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)). Therefore to achieve what you want you should specify `axis=0`

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2]])
a = np.append(a,np.array([[3,4]]), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way can be appending and then reshaping the array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([])
a = np.append(a, [2, 6])
a = np.append(a, [5, 4])
a = np.reshape(a, (2,2))
```

Comment: Hello, the values which I want to append are so many, but I know that dimensions i.e. column length would always be 2, so can you suggest how np.reshape() will work if we want to calculate the number of rows depending on the column size? e.g. if we have 10 elements then reshape() should return me array with 5 nested arrays. (10/2). How to do it

Comment: Hİ @Prasanna you are on the right track I think np.reshape(a, (rows, cols)) if cols = 2 then rows = element_number/2. But appending order would be important, be careful https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Answer (score 0):

Stick with list append.

```
a  = []
a.append( [2, 6])
a.append( [5, 4])
a = np.array(a)
```